# Disc of convergence involving logs

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Find the disc of convergence:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{z^{n}}{n(log(n))^p};(p>0)$$

I have tried geometic series, ratio test, root test...  What would be your thought on the best test to use?

Comment: The ratio test is perfectly suitable for $|z|\ne 1$.  For $|z|=1$, the integral test works.

Comment: @Dr.MV For $|z|=1$ I would say Dirichlet's test shows convergence except for the point $z=1,$ where indeed the integral test will be helpful.

Comment: Radius of convergence is 1.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Not sure this is really helpful.

Comment: @ClementC.: Of course it is helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** can you show that $n < n\log^p n < n^2$ for $n$ big enough, e.g. (for the second inequality) by proving that
$$
\frac{n\log^p n}{n^2} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0
$$
?

If so, then use the (known) radii of convergence for $\sum_n \frac{z^n}{n}$ and $\sum_n \frac{z^n}{n^2}$, by comparison.